# Can I make some text visible on a users profile if they are viewing their own profile but hide it if somebody else is viewing it?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I am using the BuddyPress plugin with WP-Job-Manager plugin for my website. I am also using another plugin called BP-job-manager to display users resumes on their Buddypress profiles. Unfortunately the BP-Job-manager Plugin is a little buggy and is not supported.

Currently if a user is logged in and they visit their own profile they can click the resumes tab and there is some text which states "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." and underneath they have options to view, edit or remove their own resumes when they hover over it.

If a user is logged in and selects to view another users profile they can also view the other users resumes but they do not have the options to edit or remove somebody else's resume but the text  "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." is still visible.

This is how it looks when I inspect it:

https://prnt.sc/qskqbd

I have temporarily used this CSS to hide it from everyone:

```
#resume-manager-candidate-dashboard > p {
    display: none;
}
```

But I still wanted it visible if a user is viewing their own profile as the features to edit and remove their resumes are still there.

I came across the "is_user_logged_in()" function online and I found an example:

```
/**
 * Give a personalized message for logged in users and a generic one for anonymous visitors
 */
function wpdocs_personal_message_when_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        printf( 'Personal Message For %s!', esc_html( $current_user->user_firstname ) );
    } else {
        echo( 'Non-Personalized Message!' );
    }
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpdocs_personal_message_when_logged_in' );
```

I was wondering if this code could be modified, for example after `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` is there anything that can be added to check whether current user is the same as the user whose profile is being viewed?

...and then `echo` the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." if user is the same?

...and then `else` the text "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below." is hidden.

I was just wondering whether there was a way of doing all this in php?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **BuddyPress** the [bp_is_my_profile](http://hookr.io/functions/bp_is_my_profile/) function can be helpful.

Change your code to the following and it'll work as you want.

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_my_profile()) {
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   printf( 'Personal Message For %s!', esc_html( $current_user->user_firstname ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I was not aware of `bp_is_my_profile`. This really helps. What I needed it for, though, was to only display a message for a user, on their own profile, if the user is logged in. The message is currently displayed on the profile page here: [link](https://prnt.sc/qskqbd) and is always visible. The text is "Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below.". I was just wondering whether there was a way I could display the message if `if (is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_my_profile()) {`
`}else{` hide it?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is using the following condition to display your message to the user:

`if(bp_is_my_profile()){
 // The HTML You want to display
}`


**By the way** you don't need to use an `else` because if the first condition is not true nothing will display so you don't need it. **Also** you don't need to add `is_user_logged_in()` _buddypress_ will take care of that using `bp_is_my_profile()` .

Comment: @ kuroyza , Oh thanks for this. I see, I added the following code: `if (is_user_logged_in() && bp_is_my_profile()) { echo '<p>Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below. </p>'; }` but instead of showing the text on the profile page it is showing in the nav menu bar/header and causing an error [link](https://prnt.sc/qup3pg). I wasn't sure why this was?

Comment: @Jas I think you have to fix the sessions warning first, because the code is not loaded correctly.
**Question:** Where did you write the code above?

Comment: @kurozya , Oh, I wrote it in the functions.php file.

Comment: @kurozya , No, not yet I am just trying to figure out how to fix the errors.

Comment: @Jas For the error, you have to remove `session_start()` from `function.php` file and put it inside your `head.php` after calling `wp_head()`  function.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<?php
$checkuser = $_SESSION[userid];
if($current_user = $checkuser){
echo 'THIS IS INFORMATIONS';
}else{
echo 'Nothing to see';
}?>
```

Please provide more information about your issue. so we look into it together.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Sure the issue is I wanted for the the text _**"Your resume can be viewed, edited or removed below."**_ on the buddypress profile page, under the resume header [link](https://prnt.sc/qskqbd), to be visible if the profile belongs to the user who is logged in and viewing it but not be visible to any other user logged in and viewing that same profile, if that makes sense... I was wondering, regarding your example, for `$_SESSION[userid];` so would `[userid]` be the user ID of the profile that was being viewed at the time?